# User picture not showing, after moving from localhost to prodution

Tags: users

I have moved my site from localhost to the web hosting, and in the web hosting, the user picture have been lost and the users cannot upload new photos. But in the localhost everything was working nicely

When i inspect the "lost picture", i get this path: `MY_SITE.com/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/pictures/MY_PICTURE-5-1375807631.jpg?itok=eQN27TLT`

I'm getting crazy with this. Is there any sugestion? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may be due to permissions issues for your files floder. Try giving permission to your `sites/default/files` folder.That will resolve your issue.

Comment: They all have permission 755 (the folders "sites", "default", and "files")

Comment: Did you check images are available in the files folder?

Comment: Give 777 for full files folder and clear the cache once. It will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You might find that updating the permissions on your files folder is necessary. Depending on your server configuration you may need to run `chmod -R 770 ~/public_html/sites/default/files` (assuming the path to your files folder) or use `777` as your permissions string.

Beyond that, ensure that when you moved to production you deployed an entire copy of the site including all the files.